# How to get HTML element properties on placing the cursor over it?

Tags: java, javascript, html, javafx

Is there any way I can get the properties of an element on which I place the cursor on? I will be using a JavaFX browser to load the websites. So I cannot use firebug or any plugins. Is there any possibility to achieve this? Please help.
Its just like Inspect Element in Firebug.

Comment: Ha! For once, a question tagged `java` and `javascript` ***correctly***!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, when this "choose an element" mode is activated, you can attach a `mouseover` handler to the document. This will receive repeated calls as the mouse moves over elements. You can tell which element the mouse is over via the `target` property on the `event` object, e.g.:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    // Use e.target to know which element it is
}, false);
```

Then simply look at the element. You might also hook `mouseout` to know when you leave an element.

There are limits to this. For instance, you can't get a list of event handlers attached to it through a normal DOM API.

Here's a simple example demonstrating the handler:

```js
var lastElement = null;
var display = document.getElementById("display");
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  if (e.target != lastElement) {
    lastElement = e.target;
    show("tag", lastElement.tagName);
    show("id", lastElement.id);
    show("name", lastElement.name);
    show("class", lastElement.className);
    show("style-color", lastElement.style.color);
    show("computed-color", getComputedStyle(lastElement).color);
  }
}, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  var n, list;
  if (e.target == lastElement) {
    list = display.querySelector("span");
    for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
      list[n].innerHTML = "";
    }
    lastElement = null;
  }
}, false);
function show(type, text) {
  display.querySelector("." + type).innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.foo {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="main-paragraph">
  This is a test, with
  <strong class="foo">various elements</strong>
  that you can
  <em style="color: blue">mouse over</em>.
  <input type="text" name="the-input">
</p>
<div id="display">
  <div>tag: <span class="tag"></span></div>
  <div>id: <span class="id"></span></div>
  <div>name: <span class="name"></span></div>
  <div>class: <span class="class"></span></div>
  <div>style.color: <span class="style-color"></span></div>
  <div>computedStyle.color: <span class="computed-color"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: its brilliant..I want to know is there a way in which I can get the properties of elements? like id, name, css, href etc?

Comment: Yes, have a look at [the DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR). `id`, `name`, and `href` are all reflected properties, as is `className` (giving the `class` attribute's value), or you could use `getAttribute` to get them. Inline style information is available as text using `getAttribute("style")`, but more usefully as parsed properties on the element's `style` object.

Comment: great. I need to load a website in JavaFX browser. It is a WebView, and when I move the mouse on any element it should give me these properties. Is it possible to do that? My JavaFX code to load website:

final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
 engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
              new ChangeListener<State>() {
                  @Override
                  public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                      if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                          engine.executeScript("<javascript here>");
}
});

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj: I've expanded the example a bit, you can take it from here. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll work on it more to customize as per my requirements :)